# Dynamic UITextView font size

Tags: objective-c, uitextview

I have a `UITextView` to present some text on it, the textView is created in code :

```
UITextView *textView = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:labelFrame];
[textView setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:prefObj.Setting_Font_Size]];
textView = NO;
textView = NSTextAlignmentJustified;
textView = [UIColor clearColor];
textView = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
[self addSubview:textView];
```

The `prefObj.Setting_Font_Size` default value is 16 ,,, the user can change the font in the setting panel ,,, once the user select a new size I want to be reflected to the `UITextView`,,, I am using this to update the font size :

```
-(void)updateFontSize
{
    [textView setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:prefObj.Setting_Font_Size]];
}
```

I am sure the value of `prefObj.Setting_Font_Size` will hold the new selected size ,,, but the text stay as it without any change ,,, how I can solve this?

Answer (score 0):

The solution was easy but I forget that the `UITextView` was created in a `UIView` class ,,,

So I make the instance of UITextView as property in the `UIView` class and change the font size where I have create the `UIView` :

the UIView subclass :

```
@interface TextToShow : UIView

@property (nonatomic, strong) UITextView *textView;

@end
```

in `UIViewController` :

```
TextToShow *TextToShowView = [[TextToShow alloc] initWithFrame:Frame];

[TextToShowView.textView setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:prefObj.Setting_Font_Size]];
```